# Cannot access to global variable in python

Tags: python, variables, global

I have declared global variable in function `a`

```
def a():
  global my_var
  my_var = 3
```

If I want to read this variable from function main, everything works

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
def main():
   print(my_var)
```

Output:

```
3
```

However I have another function b, where the var is not defined

```
def b():
  try:
    random_numbers = (random.sample(range(1, my_var), 2))
  except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'my_var' is not defined
```

Could someone explain me, why in function main I can access my_var, while in another it is not defined? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In what order are you calling the fuctions?

Comment: `a()` only creates the global variable *if you actually call the function* - and I see no sign of a call to this function anywhere in the code you posted.